# Coloring Edges in HighlightGraph: What if Edges are Named by Position Vectors?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I have some code to highlight the neighbourhood of a vertex

```
n = 30;
points = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[points, {All, 0.3}];
ngraph = NeighborhoodGraph[nng, VertexList[nng][[1]]];
ngraph = VertexDelete[ngraph, VertexList[ngraph][[1]]];
nbs = VertexList[ngraph];
T = Table[nbs[[i]] -> {Blue}, {i, 1, Length[nbs]}];
HighlightGraph[nng, ngraph, 
 VertexStyle -> Append[T, VertexList[nng][[1]] -> {Green}]]
```

but am having real trouble making the highlighted edges thick and clear, and fading the rest of the graph.

I would normally use `GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightHide"`, but even coloring the edges of the subgraph "ngraph" is a nightmare, I think because the edges are labeled as pairs of position vectors.

**How can I colour the edges of the subgraph**, and make them clearer over the unhighlighted graph?

Comment: You are not stating the problem very clearly. Are you saying that `HighlightGraph` does not work as it should?  I see that it won't highlight the vertices, so something seems wrong indeed. Hacking workaround: convert vertex names to strings: `toStr[g_?GraphQ] := 
 Graph[ToString /@ VertexList[g], Map[ToString, EdgeList[g], {2}], 
  VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[g]]`.  Use it only for visualization.   `HighlightGraph[toStr@nng, toStr@ngraph, 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightFade"]`

Comment: Just need to highlight the edges, though I can highlight the vertices quite easily

Comment: If you only want the edges highlighted, then what is wrong with `HighlightGraph[nng, EdgeList[ngraph], 
 GraphHighlightStyle -> "DehighlightFade"]`?

Comment: Hang on I will try that

Comment: How do I style those edges? Not just highlight them

Comment: What is the difference between styling and highlighting?

Comment: I think I want green edges, but the highlightgraph gives only red edges. EdgeStyle is failing

Comment: I'm out for today, but try mapping `(Style[#, Green]&)` over the edge list passed to `HighlightGraph`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will try that.